# How to fetch the transaction activities/logs for a specific table?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I can see the transaction logs with `fn_dblog`, but I need to do this for specific table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

You could try the following:

Retrieve the `id` for your user table:

```
SELECT id, name FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE NAME = '<Your_Table_Name>'
```

e.g. `658101385`

Retrieve the Transaction Log information with the undocumented function:

```
SELECT * FROM ::fn_dblog(NULL,NULL) WHERE [Lock Information] LIKE '%658101385%'
```

And then carry on from there.

**Reference:** [Identifying Object Name for CREATE and ALTER Using fn_dblog()](https://skreebydba.com/2016/08/09/identifying-object-name-for-create-and-alter-using-fn_dblog/)

Answer (score 4):

Why don't just filter on the table name?

```
select *
from fn_dblog(null, null)
where AllocUnitName = 'dbo.zzz'
```

Here is my repro when I create a table, insert 3 rows in it and delete 1 row.
Then I search for this table in the log using both methods.
I didn't miss anything important filtering directly on table name.

The two methods produce different result sets:

- "filter by table name" misses all the `LOP_LOCK_XACT` operations;
- "filter by lock info" misses everything regarding `IAM/PFS` page modifications

[image]

I might seem (e.g. from reading [Identifying Object Name for CREATE and ALTER Using fn_dblog()](https://skreebydba.com/2016/08/09/identifying-object-name-for-create-and-alter-using-fn_dblog/)) that lock information can help us to identify table name on creation, but that's not true: The `CREATE TABLE` row of `fn_dblog()` has no lock information at all.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction log is not human readable.

Depending on [the reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) behind wanting "to do this for specific table" (not specified in the question), you could look into buying a third party tool, rather than attempting it on your own.